# Correct format specifiers for custom integer types in C to ensure portability

Tags: c, cross-platform, portability

I want to know what is the right `printf` format specifier for custom integer types such as `time_t`, `socklen_t`, etc.

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
    struct addrinfo *ai;

    if (getaddrinfo("localhost", "http", NULL, &ai) != 0) {
        printf("error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("%d\n", ai->ai_addrlen);
}
```

Although this program compiles and runs fine, I am not happy about using `%d` to print `ai_addrlen` which is defined to be of type `socklen_t` in `struct addrinfo` because there is no guarantee that `socklen_t` is type `int`.

How can we correctly print such integers that are defined as `socklen_t`, `time_t`, etc.? I am concerned about portability here. I should not have to modify the format specifier when the program is compiled on a different implementation with different definitions for `socklen_t`.

Comment: Besides `size_t` there's no special format for any other standard (C, POSIX or other) types. You have to actually know what the underlying type is. Fortunately GCC and Clang are very good at knowing it and will give warnings if you use the wrong format. Unfortunately it doesn't really help if your code have to be built on different platforms with different sizes of the types though.

Comment: You have not shown the `struct` but for `size_t` you use `printf("%zu", ...);`

Comment: @WeatherVane - And, if`%zu` is not available, ***only*** then `%u` or `%lu`, though not recommended.

Comment: If in doubt, cast to the maximum available. For example `printf("%llu", (unsigned long long)ai->ai_addrlen);`

Comment: @WeatherVane: `long long` is not guaranteed to be the largest available integer, although in most current implementations it is. C99 explicitly defined `intmax_t` for that purpose.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev a previous comment said `%zu` might not be available. Although it is here, `intmax_t` is not (even 17 years since)..

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev my apologies, `intmax_t` is in `stdint.h` thank you.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Concerning "Besides `size_t` there's no special format for any other standard ... types".  There is `t` for `ptrdiff_t` such as `"td"` and `j` for `(u)intmax_t`.  Also `SCN...` and `PRI...` macros that contain _some_ string that works for those types.

Answer (score 6):

Use an intermediate cast to `intmax_t` and the `%jd` specifier:

```
printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) ai->ai_addrlen);
```

The cast enlarges the integer to an integer of the largest possible size which is able to represent the values of any other signed integer type. There is a slight caveat here: in case `sizeof(intmax_t) == sizeof ai->addrlen` and `ai->addrlen` is unsigned, large values which do not fit into a signed integer (`intmax_t`) will be truncated.

In case you are sure that the printed type is unsigned, use `uintmax_t` and `%ju` instead.

The `j` character is a "length sub-specifier" especially suited for handling the size of `intmax_t`/`uintmax_t` and it can go together with the `d` or `i` specifier characters (for `intmax_t`) or the `u`, `o`, `X` and `x` characters (for `uintmax_t`).

Answer (score 2):

[@Blagovest Buyukliev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39417655/2410359) answer is the best approach when the *sign-ness* of the type is known.

```
// if some unsigned type
printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t) ux);

// if some signed type
printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) x);
```

A challenge occurs when that sign-ness is not known.  Macro preprocessing does not account for types.  The following accounts for the sign-ness issue.  This is useful if the value is representable in only one of `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` .

```
int main(void) {
  mystery_integer_type x = rand() - RAND_MAX/2;

  // Compiler can easily optimized one of the 2 paths out
  if (x * 0 - 1 > 0) {
    printf("Unigned %ju\n", (uintmax_t) x);
  } else {
    printf("Signed %jd\n", (intmax_t) x);
  }

}
```

Note that if the type is narrower than `int/unsigned`, the path taken is well defined either way per "... one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types; ..." C11dr §6.5.2.2 6

---

A special issue occurs when trying to print `time_t`, which the C spec does not define sign-ness nor if it is an integer or floating-point, just that it is a *real type*.

For the rare case where `time_t` needs to be portable printed, some ideas, ranging from pedantic to casual.

```
    // pedantic 
    printf("%La\n", (long double) time());
    printf("%.*Le\n", LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, (long double) time());
    printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, (double) time());
    printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) time());
    printf("%lld\n", (long long) time());
    printf("%ld\n", (long) time());
    // casual
```

Note: `time()` may return `(time_t)(-1)`.

`(u)intmax_t` and some others of the above rely on C99/C11.
Portability to pre-C99 adds additional issues not discussed typically resulting in using `(long)` or `(double)`.